# String format issue in RadGrid

Tags: string, telerik, format, radgrid

While I'm trying to bind the string data to the Rad Grid it is not binding exact value which I have pulled from Data Base.

For Example I'm pulling the Data    : -   "**A                     BC                                      E F                          G**"      and binding the same data to the Rad Grid, the problem here is the rad grid column is trimming out all the spaces and displaying like     :-  "**A BC EFG**"

Here I need to bind the exact data which I'm pulling from Database. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
I am unable to replicate out this issue at my end.

My code looks like this:
```

***RadGridPage.aspx***

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="RadgridPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="RadgridPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </telerik:RadScriptManager>
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="TempTable" runat="server" Skin="MetroTouch" PageSize="5">
            <MasterTableView CssClass="TempTable" Style="border: 0; cellpadding: 0; cellspacing: 0"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="TempData" DataField="TempData">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="TempData" DataField="TempData">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

***RadGridPage.aspx.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class RadgridPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public class data { public string TempData { get; set; } }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<data> gridData = new List<data>() 
        {
        new data(){TempData="A BC E F G"},
        new data(){TempData="A BC E F G"},
        new data(){TempData="A BC E F G"},

        };
        TempTable.DataSource = gridData;

    }
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: Hi Ajay, Thanks for the reply. give more spaces between the tempdata (A        BC      E        F          G) like this. and the put put also look like the same..

Comment: i mean put some extra spaces between the words like tab space and the out put also look like the same in grid.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please update your code to:
```

***RadGridPage.aspx***

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="RadgridPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="RadgridPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </telerik:RadScriptManager>
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="TempTable" runat="server" Skin="MetroTouch" PageSize="5" OnItemDataBound="gvSpecs_ItemDataBound">
            <MasterTableView CssClass="TempTable" Style="border: 0; cellpadding: 0; cellspacing: 0"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="TempData" UniqueName="TempDataA" DataField="TempData">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="TempData" UniqueName="TempDataB" DataField="TempData">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**RadGridPage.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Telerik.Web.UI;

public partial class RadgridPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public class data { public string TempData { get; set; } }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<data> gridData = new List<data>() 
        {
        new data(){TempData="A  BC E F G"},
        new data(){TempData="A      BC E F G"},
        new data(){TempData="A          BC E F G"},

        };
        TempTable.DataSource = gridData;

    }

    protected void gvSpecs_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
        {
            GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
            TableCell cellA = (TableCell)item["TempDataA"];
            cellA.Text = cellA.Text.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
            TableCell cellB = (TableCell)item["TempDataB"];
            cellB.Text = cellB.Text.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
        }
    }
}
```